# How to import an Access database into MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mysql-workbench, migrate, workbench

I have a database in Access that I am trying to migrate into MySQL Workbench.  The Migrate option in the MySQL Workbench does not work properly, as it keeps giving an error saying "ODBC Administrator utility could not be found."  I downloaded a ODBC Data Source Administrator, but that did not help.  I downloaded MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0 but it will not let me complete the setup of this, it just freezes every time and won't let me click "next" after a certain point.  What am I missing, how can I make this work?

Comment: I get the following error log when I try to run the MySQL Workbench migration

Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting to source...
Connecting to ...
Opening ODBC connection to DSN=...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\migration_source_selection.py", line 439, in task_connect
    if not self.main.plan.migrationSource.connect():
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\migration.py", line 199, in connect
    self._rev_eng_module.connect(self.connection, self.password or "")

Comment: SystemError: InterfaceError("('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')"): error calling Python module function DbMsAccessRE.connect

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 71, in run
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench

Comment: 8.0\modules\migration_source_selection.py", line 457, in task_connect
    username = self.main.plan.migrationSource.connection.parameterValues.userName
KeyError: 'grt.Dict key must be a string'
ERROR: Error during Connect to source DBMS: 'grt.Dict key must be a string'
ERROR: Exception in task 'Connect to source DBMS': KeyError('grt.Dict key must be a string')

Failed

Comment: I just tried the latest version of MySQL Workbench and the Migration Wizard worked for me despite Workbench reporting that Windows 8.1 was an "unsupported operating system". What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: I am running Windows 10 Home

Comment: You could use [AceOdbcCheck](https://github.com/gordthompson/AceOdbcCheck) to see whether you have the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine installed. `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\…` indicates that Workbench is running as a 64-bit application.